# Add hypens to vehicle registration number in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to add hypens to textfield when the user enters the vehicle Registration Number. e.g to make it KA-01-BR-1234 as the user types. I have implemented below method, but am looking for a better way to do this, if there is. Any answers will be helpful. thanks

[image: KA01BR1234]

**I tried something like this:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 909090 {
            if textField.text!.count > 13 {
                return false
            }

            if range.length == 0 && (range.location == 2 || range.location == 5 || range.location == 8) {
                textField.text = "\(textField.text!)-\(string)"
                return false
            }

            return true
        }

        return true
    }
```

This will not work if the user enters **KA01R1234** ( B missing).

[image]

**My second approach is this (still horrible but currently working):**

```
extension String {
    ///Add Hypen for Vehicle Registration No.
    func addHypen() -> String {
        var finalStr = ""
        self.forEach { (charact) in
            if let newStr = finalStr.last, (newStr.isLetter && charact.isNumber) || (newStr.isNumber && charact.isLetter) {
                finalStr.append("-")
                finalStr.append(charact)
            } else if !charact.isWhitespace || !charact.isSymbol || !charact.isMathSymbol {
                finalStr.append(charact)
            }
        }

        return finalStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "-")
    }
}
```

and then just calling the function on the string when `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```
textfield.text = textfield.text.addHypen()
```

Any better solutions, please welcome!

Comment: why not use regex to verify the text is correctly formatted ?

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with the regex with @chirag90, I think it will work. thanks btw. will try to work on that.